# Windows 8.1 keyboard driver issue

Tags: drivers, keyboard, windows-8.1

I have successfully reinstalled a keyboard driver after having an issue (NumLock acts as Volume up -- nothing too bad -- but SPACEBAR acts as volume down!). Without having to resort to disabling fast startup (maybe a better solution than installing an older version of BOOTMGR, really, to avoid the OS Choice graphical screen, which is the cause) how can I fix this?
A smaller, nonimportant thing, is starting an autohotkey script in all sessions (it's compiled, it changes a few shortcut keys on the session, namely two keys that I don't use and now could use as actual volume keys -- I don't have media buttons)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it is a Function Key. F1, F2 and other Functions keys allow you to adjust monitor brightness, volume and such.

You can use FN for the moment. Functions Keys are deep in the BIOS but could be re-mapped by most programs. Re-installing the keyboard would be the best way to solve the problem.

As for the Hotkey Script, it's because you added it as a startup item in the Boot Manager. You can ask it through Task Manager.

I would suggest not use Hotkey Scripts to remap. It's recommended in the Help Pages. You should use AutoHotkey to create Hotkeys solely or for automation.

Remapping keys with autohotkey is a common error.

Comment: Um, no. I don't have Fn, nor real Media keys. I have actually dismantled the keyboard, washed it, dried it, put it back and now the issue is different (the numpad keys are practically unusable). I have done a modification to the scancode map of Windows. Most of the numpad keys do nothing now. The top row has special functions (Assigned NumLock to Play/Pause, / and * to volume keys and - to "This PC". Also assigned RWin and the menu key to previous and next track.

Comment: Maybe I will dismantle the keyboard again and remake it in such a way it doesn't have these new problems either. The keyboard is a standard 102-key (or 101, I don't know, I didn't count the number of buttons there when putting each of them back...), without FN or the such (Doesn't have a (< >) key). The keyboard is over 6 years old, I forgot to say, and it started recently (I've seen the wrong scancodes in another micro operating system which could display what scancodes it was getting) So the problem was hardware now. No software errors.